smoothing in parabolic equations
Consider the parabolic equation
$$\partial_t u  = \Delta u + u^5$$
on $[0,T)\times \mathbb{R^3}$ with initial data $u(0,x)=u_0\in L^{6}(\mathbb{R}^3).$ The equation is well-posed in this space, but I was wondering if we can deduce that for all $t>0$ we have $u(t)\in W^{2,6/5}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $W^{k,p}$ is the sobolev space with $|D^{\alpha}u|\in L^p$ for $|\alpha|\leq k.$ I know this is true for elliptic equations, but I am not sure if one can deduce this for parabolic equations as well. In particular this estimate would imply that $u\in W^{2,6/5}\subset W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by Sobolev embedding.

A First comment : Your last embedding cannot hold. One has the critical Sobolev embedding $W^{2,6/5}\hookrightarrow W^{1,2}$, this would imply that $W^{1,2}=W^{2,6/5}$, which does not hold.
Second comment: I don't understand your statement "I know this is true for elliptic equations" but elliptic equations does not have a prescribed initial value. Did you mean $$-\Delta u = u^5$$ has a unique solution in $W^{2,6/5}$ ?

Finally, the tool you are looking for is called $\mathrm{L}^q(\mathrm{L}^p)$- maximal regularity and also need to consider the interaction between time and space regularity. I won't elaborate that much right now. The idea is to construct a solution by a fixed point theorem under a smallness assumption for the norm of the initial data (probably $\mathrm{L}^6$ wouldn't fit your purpose in the end). This is not the only approach but probably one of the smoothest.

@ToGle thanks for pointing that out, what I meant was that in general $\Delta u =f$ with $f\in L^p$ implies that $u\in W^{2,p}$ by calderon-zygmund theory

What I wanted to know is an analogue of this for parabolic PDEs, I thought the heuristic is that you gain one derivative in time and two in space which is why I expect that once the flow starts we should be in $u(t)$ should be in $W^{2,6/5}$ since the nonlinearity in $L^{6/5}$

That's not true in general, the solution $u$ may have second order derivatives $\nabla^2 u\in\mathrm{L}^p$ (by C-Z theory as you said), BUT since we are in the whole space case, in general $u$ itself does not belong to $\mathrm{L}^p$.

@ToGle Oh I see so then if start with $u \in \dot{H}^1$ then is it safe to say that $u\in \dot{H}^3$ at later times?

This will depend on the kind of regularity you put to see your function as a function of time. This is a bit more trickier than that. There is really an interplay between time and space regularity. For instance, for $u_0\in\dot{\mathrm{H}}^1$, one has $e^{t\Delta}u_0\in\mathrm{L}^2_t(\dot{\mathrm{H}}^2)$ but also have $e^{t\Delta}u_0\in\mathrm{L}^\infty_t(\dot{\mathrm{H}}^1)$, and this is optimal. So depending on the amount of regularity-integrability in-time you don't have access to the same amount regularity in space.

Oh I see, my initial goal was to get $\int_{t_0}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |u|^{10} dx dt<+\infty$ for some $t_0>0$ in the case when the flow is global, i.e. $T=+\infty.$ This would morally require to check that $u\in L^2_t \dot{H}_x^2\subset L^{10}_t L^{10}_x$ right?
